# how to add users in spring security core

Tags: grails, groovy, spring-security

I just added the spring security plugin to my grails application.  I have a question about adding users and their associated roles.  I am able to do it correctly in the bootstrap but was wondering how to do it in the GSP page.  I have a gsp page with the corresponding fields.  when submited, it call the save method.  my user domain controller extends SecUser.  below is the example:

```
class User extends SecUser {

    String  fname
    String  lname
    Date    dateCreated
    Date    lastUpdated

    static constraints = {
        fname       (blank:false)
        lname       (blank:false)
    }
    String toString(){
        fname & " " & lname
    }
}
```

When the user is saved, it saves only items in the user domain, not the SecUser.  Does anyone have an example GSP and controller code to save the all the user data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I perceive that you have two problems :

1. How to create a Crud (including gsp) on your User class
2. How to persist the data on your class and its inherited fields

For the first question:
To create GSPs and everything you need to have a CRUD on your User class, I suggest that you use scaffolding. If will take care of all of this for you.

Remove everything from your UserController or create another controller with only the following code:

```
class UserController {
    static scaffold = User
}
```

then, navigate to your UserController ({your_app}/user/index) and everything should be there.

If you want to have an actual controller and gsps and modify how they work, use the grails command :`grails generate-all your.package.User`

For the second question :

Unless there is a problem with your SecUser class (transient fields for example), all fields inherited from SecUser should be saved through a User.save()

Let me know how it goes,

Vincent Giguère

Comment: thanks this helped.  I'm sorry i didnt check this earlier.  I wasnt aware it was required

Answer (score 0):

Did you use the included script to generate your User class?

> grails s2-quickstart
>   DOMAIN_CLASS_PACKAGE USER_CLASS_NAME
>   ROLE_CLASS_NAME
>   [REQUESTMAP_CLASS_NAME]

eg.

> grails s2-quickstart com.yourapp User Authority

When I did that in my grails app, the resulting User class did not extend SecUser.

Comment: i think you might be confused with my question.  right now i add users in my bootstrap using this code:                                           def newUser= new mgr.User(username:"newUser",password:springSecurityService.encodePassword("admin"), fname:"Jason",lname:"lname", dateCreate:today, lastUpdated:today, enabled:true)    
newUser.save() 
SecUserSecRole.create newUser, adminRole                                                                 my question is, how do i add a user in my GSP and controller files?

Comment: thanks for responding.  No, I wanted to extend SecUser.  when i added the Security Core I already had a User domain so I just wanted to extend it.  The problem is, when i generate the views, the Create and Edit Views do not add anything for the Role.  I was able to write my own code to add users but when I want to delete  the user I am unable as I can figure out how to get the SecUser and SecRole of the user to delete (i do know the primary key of the user but that does not seem to be enough to delete)  any help would be great